# Which of the statements are true about the set $E \subseteq \Bbb R^3\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, open-map

> Let $f : \Bbb R^3 \longrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be given by $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (e^{x_2} \cos x_1, e^{x_2} \sin x_1, 2x_1 - \cos x_3).$$ Consider a set $$\begin{align*} E & = \left \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb R^3\ \bigg |\ \text {there exists an open subset}\ U\ \text {around}\ (x_1,x_2,x_3)\ \text {such that}\ f\vert_U\ \text {is an open map} \right \}. \end{align*}$$ Then which of the following are true?

> $(1)$ $E = \Bbb R^3$

> $(2)$ $E$ is countable

> $(3)$ $E$ is not countable but not $\Bbb R^3$

> $(4)$ $\left \{\left (x_1,x_2, \dfrac {\pi} {2} \right )\ \bigg |\ x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R \right \}$ is a proper subset of $E$

How do I proceed? Can anybody please give me some hint?

Thanks for your time.

**Source** $:$ CSIR NET JUNE $2019.$

Comment: @Digitalis I don't know how to approach this question?

Comment: What about using the inverse function theorem ?

Comment: Oh! I see @Digitalis. The Jacobian determinant is $-e^{x_2} \sin x_3 \neq 0$ for $x_3 = \dfrac {\pi} {2}.$ So by inverse function theorem it follows that option $(4)$ is the correct and hence option $(2)$ is false. Now if the Jacobian determinant of $f$ is $0$ at a point $p$ that doesn't imply that $f$ is not open in any neighbourhood of $p.$ Right? But then which one of $(1)$ and $(3)$ is the correct option?